# sudo yarn build failing - each(@input-number-wrapper-cls, { ^ Function 'each' is undefined

Tags: node.js, npm, less, antd, yarnpkg

I am trying to run `sudo yarn build` to build our teams react application locally.

Right now the build is failing due to what seems like a library issue with ant-d perhaps.

Below is the output of the `sudo yarn build` command.
➜  nova-web git:(feature/tech-improvement-1204122945262264) ✗ sudo yarn build
yarn run v1.22.19
$ node --max-old-space-size=4096 scripts/build.js
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

```
./node_modules/antd/lib/input-number/style/index.less (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-8-1!./node_modules/@nodeworks/antd-scss-theme-plugin/build/dist/lib/antdLessLoader.js??ref--6-oneOf-8-2!./node_modules/antd/lib/input-number/style/index.less)

each(@input-number-wrapper-cls, {
^
Function 'each' is undefined
      in /Users/apple/Documents/projects/nova-web/node_modules/antd/lib/input-number/style/status.less (line 7, column 0)


error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Here is the `package.json` file

```
{
  "name": "nova-web",
  "version": "21.1.0",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.8.4",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-typescript": "^7.12.1",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.5",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.5",
    "@loadable/component": "^5.12.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.0",
    "@mui/material": "^5.11.0",
    "@mui/styled-engine-sc": "^5.11.0",
    "@mui/x-data-grid": "^5.17.19",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.2",
    "@sentry/react": "^5.19.2",
    "@svgr/webpack": "4.3.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "12.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "13.2.1",
    "@types/classnames": "^2.2.10",
    "@types/crypto-js": "^3.1.44",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.2",
    "@types/js-cookie": "^2.2.6",
    "@types/loadable__component": "^5.10.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.149",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/pluralize": "^0.0.29",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "@types/react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "@types/react-html-parser": "^2.0.1",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.7",
    "@types/react-router": "^5.1.4",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.3",
    "@types/react-sticky": "^6.0.3",
    "@types/react-timeago": "^4.1.1",
    "@types/recharts": "^1.8.14",
    "@types/smoothscroll-polyfill": "^0.3.1",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.26",
    "accesscontrol": "^2.2.1",
    "antd": "^4.7.2",
    "array-move": "^3.0.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "babel-eslint": "10.0.3",
    "babel-jest": "27.2.1",
    "babel-loader": "8.0.6",
    "babel-plugin-import": "^1.13.0",
    "babel-plugin-named-asset-import": "^0.3.6",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^9.1.1",
    "camelcase": "^5.3.1",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.3.0",
    "chai": "^4.3.4",
    "change-case": "^4.1.1",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "crypto-js": "^4.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^3.4.2",
    "cypress": "^9.0.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.13.0",
    "dnd-core": "^10.0.2",
    "dotenv": "8.2.0",
    "dotenv-expand": "5.1.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^5.2.0",
    "eslint-loader": "3.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^1.6.1",
    "file-loader": "4.3.0",
    "fs-extra": "^8.1.0",
    "graphql-request": "^1.8.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "4.0.0-beta.11",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "immutability-helper": "^3.0.2",
    "immutable": "^4.0.0-rc.12",
    "jest": "27.2.1",
    "jest-watch-typeahead": "0.4.2",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
    "json-to-graphql-query": "^2.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.10.0",
    "mixpanel-browser": "^2.40.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.33",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
    "normalizr": "^3.6.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "5.0.3",
    "pluralize": "^8.0.0",
    "pnp-webpack-plugin": "1.6.0",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "4.1.0",
    "postcss-loader": "3.0.0",
    "postcss-normalize": "8.0.1",
    "postcss-preset-env": "6.7.0",
    "postcss-safe-parser": "4.0.1",
    "query-string": "^6.12.0",
    "quill-mention": "^3.1.0",
    "rc-tree-select": "^4.1.2",
    "react": "^16.13.0",
    "react-add-to-homescreen": "^1.1.0",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^1.0.6",
    "react-cookie": "^4.0.3",
    "react-dev-utils": "^10.2.0",
    "react-device-detect": "^1.14.0",
    "react-dnd": "^10.0.2",
    "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^10.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.0",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-hook-inview": "^4.3.8",
    "react-html-parser": "^2.0.2",
    "react-lines-ellipsis": "^0.14.1",
    "react-markdown": "^5.0.3",
    "react-material-ui-carousel": "^3.4.2",
    "react-mixpanel": "^1.0.5",
    "react-mixpanel-browser": "^3.1.4",
    "react-quill": "2.0.0-beta.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "react-router": "^5.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-sortable-hoc": "^2.0.0",
    "react-sticky": "^6.0.3",
    "react-textarea-autosize": "^8.3.4",
    "react-timeago": "^4.4.0",
    "recharts": "^1.8.5",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "resolve": "1.15.0",
    "resolve-url-loader": "3.1.1",
    "sass-loader": "^7.3.1",
    "semver": "6.3.0",
    "smoothscroll-polyfill": "^0.4.4",
    "style-loader": "^1.1.3",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.6",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "2.3.4",
    "timeago-react": "^3.0.0",
    "ts-pnp": "1.1.5",
    "ttl-counter": "^1.0.3",
    "typescript": "~4.7.3",
    "url-loader": "2.3.0",
    "use-query-params": "^1.1.9",
    "webpack": "4.41.5",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.10.2",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "2.2.0",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "4.3.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node scripts/start.js",
    "serve": "serve -s -p 5000 build",
    "build": "node --max-old-space-size=4096 scripts/build.js",
    "build:serve": "yarn build && serve -s build",
    "test": "node scripts/test.js --watchAll=false",
    "test:watch": "yarn test --watchAll",
    "test:coverage": "yarn test --coverage --watchAll=false",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook",
    "cy:open": "NODE_ENV=production cypress open",
    "cy:run": "NODE_ENV=production cypress run --record --key XXX",
    "cy:build:open": "NODE_ENV=production start-server-and-test build:serve http://localhost:5000 cy:open",
    "cy:build:run": "NODE_ENV=production start-server-and-test build:serve http://localhost:5000 cy:run",
    "lint": "eslint './src/**' --quiet",
    "lint-fix": "eslint './src/**' --fix"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "staging": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react-app"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/helper-define-map": "^7.13.12",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.13.0",
    "@nodeworks/antd-scss-theme-plugin": "^2.0.3",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.5.15",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.5.15",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.5.15",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.5.15",
    "@testing-library/cypress": "^8.0.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.29.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.29.0",
    "antd-scss-theme-plugin": "^1.0.8",
    "cypress-dotenv": "^2.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.12.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.21.5",
    "jsdom": "^17.0.0",
    "less-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "serve": "^12.0.0",
    "start-server-and-test": "^1.12.5",
    "storybook-readme": "^5.0.9",
    "ts-jest": "^27.0.5",
    "tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin": "^3.3.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Function 'each' is undefined

Comment: Yes that is the message. That function is in a library that we do not manage or own. It's Ant Design https://ant.design/